# How to disable apollo sandbox and launch playground?

Tags: node.js, apollo-server, graphql-playground

I was using apollo-server and when I needed to get access to the playground I only put localhost:4000 and I got access to Playground, but now when I try to get access to playground is redirected to the sandbox, the question is about how can I disable that behaviour and launch playground instead of the sandbox.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This change that you're experiencing might have been caused by upgrading (maybe accidentally or automatically) from Apollo Server v2 to v3. [The v3.0.0 release of Apollo Server](https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-server/blob/main/CHANGELOG.md#v300) happened 10 days ago.

Apollo Server v3 changed the default behavior of the server's landing page, but you can still configure the GraphQL Playground by following [these instructions](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/apollo-server/api/plugin/landing-pages/#graphql-playground-landing-page).

```js
import { ApolloServer } from "apollo-server";
import {
  ApolloServerPluginLandingPageGraphQLPlayground
} from "apollo-server-core";

const server = new ApolloServer({
  typeDefs,
  resolvers,
  plugins: [
    ApolloServerPluginLandingPageGraphQLPlayground(),
  ],
});
```

Comment: its not working for v4

Comment: For v4, use the npm : @apollo/server-plugin-landing-page-graphql-playground
https://www.apollographql.com/docs/apollo-server/api/plugin/landing-pages/#graphql-playground-landing-page